# Test class with a new() call in it with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a legacy class that contains a `new()` call to instantiate a `LoginContext` object:

```
public class TestedClass {
  public LoginContext login(String user, String password) {
    LoginContext lc = new LoginContext("login", callbackHandler);
  }
}
```

I want to test this class using Mockito to mock the `LoginContext` as it requires that the JAAS security stuff be set up before instantiating, but I'm not sure how to do that without changing the `login()` method to externalize the `LoginContext`.

Is it possible using Mockito to mock the `LoginContext` class?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

For the future I would recommend [Eran Harel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5920394/1898563) (refactoring moving `new` to factory that can be mocked). But if you don't want to change the original source code, use very handy and unique feature: **spies**. From the [documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13):

> You can create spies of real objects. When you use the spy then the **real** methods are called (unless a method was stubbed).
>
> Real spies should be used **carefully and occasionally**, for example when dealing with legacy code.

In your case you should write:

```
TestedClass tc = spy(new TestedClass());
LoginContext lcMock = mock(LoginContext.class);
when(tc.login(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(lcMock);
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thanks Tomasz.  The extra part at the bottom of the doco about doReturn was especially helpful.

Comment: any alternative for versions less than 1.8

Comment: Yes, using a factory that can be mocked is the real answer here. Using spy is controversial, and IMO to be avoided.

Comment: link 404: http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13

Comment: _refactoring moving new to factory that can be mocked_ I don't get this. You've just moved the same problem to a new place.

Comment: when you use spy you are not actually testing that method

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider yes but in the new place (normally your test class) you can code the factory to return an object which you instantiate in your test rather,  so you can use the object in test verifications.

Comment: Using @Spy annotation did the trick, thanks a lot for the detailed description.

Comment: I had a similar situation (with an old code) and I went with spy but with a backlog to change it by using factory instead (reason: Instead of saying I will only mock just a part of "class under test" leaving everything else real, I would prefer moving that part (dependency) into a factory)

Comment: @bwobbones what about testing this factory, it isn't the same problem?

Comment: @JonasFreire The factory class would only have the code for creating new instances with NO business logic involved. So, there's no point in testing it. We wouldn't wanna test if `new()` really returns a new instance. :)

Answer (score 72):

I am all for [Eran Harel's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5920394/2422776) and in cases where it isn't possible, [Tomasz Nurkiewicz's suggestion for spying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5920815/2422776) is excellent. However, it's worth noting that there are situations where neither would apply. E.g. if the `login` method was a bit "beefier":

```
public class TestedClass {
    public LoginContext login(String user, String password) {
        LoginContext lc = new LoginContext("login", callbackHandler);
        lc.doThis();
        lc.doThat();
        return lc;
    }
}
```

... and this was old code that could not be refactored to extract the initialization of a new `LoginContext` to its own method and apply one of the aforementioned solutions.

For completeness' sake, it's worth mentioning a third technique - using [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock) to inject the mock object when the `new` operator is called. PowerMock isn't a silver bullet, though. It works by applying byte-code manipulation on the classes it mocks, which could be dodgy practice if the tested classes employ byte code manipulation or reflection and at least from my personal experience, has been known to introduce a performance hit to the test. Then again, if there are no other options, the only option must be the good option:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(TestedClass.class)
public class TestedClassTest {

    @Test
    public void testLogin() {
        LoginContext lcMock = mock(LoginContext.class);
        whenNew(LoginContext.class).withArguments(anyString(), anyString()).thenReturn(lcMock);
        TestedClass tc = new TestedClass();
        tc.login ("something", "something else");
        // test the login's logic
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Modern versions of Mockito provide similar functionality without needing the extra PowerMock library with the `mockito-inline` dependency (instead of the `mockito-core` dependency):

```java
public class TestedClassTest {
    @Test
    public void testLogin() {
        try (MockedConstruction<LoginContext> mockedConstruction = 
             Mockito.mockConstruction(LoginContext.class)) {
            TestedClass tc = new TestedClass();
            tc.login("something", "something else");
            // test the login's logic
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for stating the scenario which is generally the case as most of the methods which need this and where refactoring is not possible/difficult is old/legacy code!

Comment: the big problem with this approach is that you have to include the `TestedClass` in the `@PrepareForTest` which automatically makes the whole class coverage being 0 both in sonar and eclemma. This might be due to a bug in one of the coverage analysis tools

Comment: `if there are no other options, the only option must be the good option` +1 For Mr. Sherlock Holmes. ;)

Comment: I would have voted twice up if it was possible: once for the efficient answer and once more for the respectful intro to your answer. BTW, I also voted up for Tomasz Nurkiewicz' answer

Comment: I am following this but it is not working. Is there any change to this workaround?

Comment: Powermock [does not work with JUnit5](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/929) at the moment 

Comment: In that situation, simply refactor the login method and create method that creates just the LoginContext.

Answer (score 36):

You can use a factory to create the login context. Then you can mock the factory and return whatever you want for your test.

```
public class TestedClass {
  private final LoginContextFactory loginContextFactory;

  public TestedClass(final LoginContextFactory loginContextFactory) {
    this.loginContextFactory = loginContextFactory;
  }

  public LoginContext login(String user, String password) {
    LoginContext lc = loginContextFactory.createLoginContext();
  }
}

public interface LoginContextFactory {
  public LoginContext createLoginContext();
}
```

Comment: In this case, I will need to create an implementation of LoginContextFactory which just returns a new object of LoginContext? Is that correct?

Comment: This will require that each class I have needs to have a factory. For POJOs, I find it to be an overkill to create such factories. Are there other alternatives of a test framework?

Comment: @alltej you only need to use factories in the classes which are instantiating new objects - not every pojo surely?

Comment: Where will be the "new LoginContext("login", callbackHandler);" in the new code?

Comment: @Denly normally that would be in your setup code, e.g. in a DI framework, or in your main where you initialize your app

Comment: Why are we not passing in the user and password to loginContextFactory.createLoginContext() method? Or are we not supposed to? What does the LoginContextFactoryImpl look like? Would have been great to expand on the answer.

Comment: @Adam wouldn't you need a new factory for every different class that has a new instance? For instance if Class X calls new A() and new B(). Wouldn't Class X need to have two factories injected?

Comment: +1 for @Kosi question. How in the case creating factories different from refactoring to dependency injection instead?

Answer (score 5):

```
    public class TestedClass {
    public LoginContext login(String user, String password) {
        LoginContext lc = new LoginContext("login", callbackHandler);
        lc.doThis();
        lc.doThat();
    }
  }
```

-- Test Class:

```
    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PrepareForTest(TestedClass.class)
    public class TestedClassTest {

        @Test
        public void testLogin() {
            LoginContext lcMock = mock(LoginContext.class);
            whenNew(LoginContext.class).withArguments(anyString(), anyString()).thenReturn(lcMock);
//comment: this is giving mock object ( lcMock )
            TestedClass tc = new TestedClass();
            tc.login ("something", "something else"); ///  testing this method.
            // test the login's logic
        }
    }
```

When calling the actual method `tc.login ("something", "something else");` from the testLogin() {
- This LoginContext lc is set to null and throwing NPE  while calling `lc.doThis();`

Answer (score 4):

Not that I know of, but what about doing something like this when you create an instance of TestedClass that you want to test:

```
TestedClass toTest = new TestedClass() {
    public LoginContext login(String user, String password) {
        //return mocked LoginContext
    }
};
```

Another option would be to use Mockito to create an instance of TestedClass and let the mocked instance return a LoginContext.

Answer (score 3):

I happened to be in a particular situation where my usecase resembled the one of [Mureinik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30137217/4163254) but I ended-up using the solution of [Tomasz Nurkiewicz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5920815/4163254).

Here is how:

```java
class TestedClass extends AARRGGHH {
    public LoginContext login(String user, String password) {
        LoginContext lc = new LoginContext("login", callbackHandler);
        lc.doThis();
        lc.doThat();
        return lc;
    }
}
```

Now, `PowerMockRunner` failed to initialize `TestedClass` because it extends `AARRGGHH`, which in turn does more contextual initialization... You see where this path was leading me: I would have needed to mock on several layers. Clearly a HUGE smell.

I found a [nice hack](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Mocking-Object-Creation) with minimal refactoring of `TestedClass`: I created a small method

```
LoginContext initLoginContext(String login, CallbackHandler callbackHandler) {
    new lc = new LoginContext(login, callbackHandler);
}
```

The scope of this method is necessarily `package`.

Then your test stub will look like:

```java
LoginContext lcMock = mock(LoginContext.class)
TestedClass testClass = spy(new TestedClass(withAllNeededArgs))
doReturn(lcMock)
    .when(testClass)
    .initLoginContext("login", callbackHandler)
```

and the trick is done...

Answer (score 2):

In situations where the class under test can be modified and when it's desirable to avoid byte code manipulation, to keep things fast or to minimise third party dependencies, here is my take on the use of a factory to extract the `new` operation.

```
public class TestedClass {

    interface PojoFactory { Pojo getNewPojo(); }

    private final PojoFactory factory;

    /** For use in production - nothing needs to change. */
    public TestedClass() {
        this.factory = new PojoFactory() {
            @Override
            public Pojo getNewPojo() {
                return new Pojo();
            }
        };
    }

    /** For use in testing - provide a pojo factory. */
    public TestedClass(PojoFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        Pojo pojo = this.factory.getNewPojo();
        anythingCouldHappen(pojo);
    }
}
```

With this in place, your testing, asserts and verify calls on the Pojo object are easy:

```
public  void testSomething() {
    Pojo testPojo = new Pojo();
    TestedClass target = new TestedClass(new TestedClass.PojoFactory() {
                @Override
                public Pojo getNewPojo() {
                    return testPojo;
                }
            });
    target.doSomething();
    assertThat(testPojo.isLifeStillBeautiful(), is(true));
}
```

The only downside to this approach potentially arises if `TestClass` has multiple constructors which you'd have to duplicate with the extra parameter.

For SOLID reasons you'd probably want to put the PojoFactory interface onto the Pojo class instead, and the production factory as well.

```
public class Pojo {

    interface PojoFactory { Pojo getNewPojo(); }

    public static final PojoFactory productionFactory = 
        new PojoFactory() {
            @Override 
            public Pojo getNewPojo() {
                return new Pojo();
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an interceptor method that can replace the original object with a mocked object.

```
public class TestedClass {

    private LoginContext interceptedLoginContext;

    public LoginContext login(String user, String password) {
        LoginContext lc = intercept(new LoginContext("login", callbackHandler));
    }

    public LoginContext intercept(LoginContext loginContext) {
        return this.interceptedLoginContext == null ? loginContext : interceptedLoginContext;
    }

    public void setIntercepted(LoginContext loginContext) {
        this.interceptedLoginContext = loginContext;
    }

}
```

So you will need to set the object before method execution.