# Unit Testing using Mockito or JMock

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, jmock

Unit Testing:

I have the following classes

```
public class BImpl extends AImpl
{
    public BImpl(final C c) 
    {
        super(c);
    }

    public String getInfo()
    {
       final String info = getInformation();
       // Do all my logic here
       return info;
    }
}

public abstract class AImpl
{
    public String getInformation()
    {
    // some logic...returns String.
    }
}
```

I am trying to unit test the method getInfo() by using any of the mocking methods available either Mockito or JMock.

for example when using Mockito I am using this way:

```
final AImpl aImpl = mock(AImpl.class);
when(aImpl.getInformation()).thenReturn("ABC");
```

Now since I have to create an instance of BImpl the only way I can create is using the constructor available.

```
final BImpl bImpl = new BImpl (C);
bImpl.getInfo();
```

when it calls into the getInfo() method and it tries to call getInformation(), it isn't calling the mocked object but calling the actual one.

What is the good way to test this method.
Is there any other way I can create an instance of BImpl without going by the constructor that I have given above?

Thanks!!

Comment: I'm afraid there are several layers of wrong in your code which makes it difficult to give practical answers back. It has to do with what C is for. Right now, the code won't compile because AImpl does not have a constructor that takes the C.

Comment: I didn't mention the full AImpl class. But the AImpl class does have the constructor as needed.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO it's not a problem with mocking libraries but with your design. You want to test `getInfo()` method by mocking `getInformation()` on which it depends. Unit testing a method mocking all its dependencies is a right way to go and all mocking frameworks support it pretty well. So why you experience these problems?

Because you have chosen inheritance where composition was actually needed. You are abusing inheritance to implement *uses* relationship, whereas it should have been composition. Inheriting from a class just to have a convenient access to its methods is asking for trouble. Think of extending `EntityManager` by every repository/DAO...

You should refactor your code first so that `BImpl` **has** `AImpl` and the latter one is injected somehow. Then you can let some DI framework to perform the injection in production code (or do it yourself) with real implementation while injecting mock in unit test.

Comment: I do understand what you mean, but this was a poor design and has being there for a long time which cannot be changed now. Now I am adding this new method getInfo() into it and since there were no unit tests, I am planning on adding it but this isn't allowing me to. I am looking over for some alternative to do this or if you guys know any other way to test this method without changing the existing implementation of the classes

Comment: OK, I believe *spying* feature in Mockito might help you (see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920153/test-class-with-a-new-call-in-it-with-mockito/5920815#5920815)). You have to spy on `getInformation()`.