# How to mock Objects that are not passed as arguments

Tags: java, testing, mocking, mockito

Imagine the following class

```
public class ClassToBeTested{

  private AnotherClass otherClass;

  public void methodToBeTested(){
     otherClass = new AnotherClass();
     String temp = otherClass.someMethod()

    // ...some other code that depends on temp

  }

}
```

Now, if `methodToBeTested` was designed to accept an instance of `AnotherClass` I could easily create a mock of `AnotherClass` and tell Mockito to return a value i prefeer when `someMethod()` is called. However as the above code is designed AFAIK it's not possible to mock `AnotherClass` and testing this method will depend on what `someMethod()` returns.

Is there anyway I can test the above code without beeing dependent on what `someMethod()` returns using Mockito or any other framework?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920153/test-class-with-a-new-call-in-it-with-mockito

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If available you can use the Spring `ReflectionTestUtils` `setField` method:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html#setField%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29

If not write your own its pretty straight forward using reflection, some info here:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Reflection/Setprivatefieldvalue.htm

Something like the below, you will need additional error handling to get this to work properly:

```
public void setField(Object obj, String fieldName, Object value) {
    Field f = obj.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    f.setAccessible(true);
    f.set(obj, value);
}
```

It can then be called like this:

```
setField(objUnderTest, "fieldToSet", mockObject);
```

---

### edit

I have just noticed that you are instantiating it inside the method. If that is absolutely necessary then you should follow the possible duplicate link posted by cyroxx.
Although that practice is often a sign of bad design so if you can take it out I would.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the field by reflection as suggested in the other answer will work.

But if you're doing this sort of thing often, I'd recommend PowerMock (in conjunction with Mockito) or JMockIt to achieve this. Both allow you to mock constructors, statics, final fields... in short, just about anything. Very useful with legacy code.

However, when you're writing new code, and your class has a dependency on another class that you want to isolate in this way, you should consider changing the design so that the other object is passed in to your class instead of being instantiated by it. Search for "Dependency injection" and you'll find plenty...

Answer (score 1):

As a quick fix, I usually wrap the call to `new`:

```
protected newAnotherClass() { return new AnotherClass(); }
```

That way, I can overwrite this method from a unit test. It's dirty but it's quick :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [JMockit](http://jmockit.org) test which does what you want, very simply:

```
@Test
public void testTheMethodToBeTested(@Mocked final AnotherClass dep)
{
    new NonStrictExpectations() {{ dep.someMethod(); result = "whatever"; }};

    new ClassToBeTested().methodToBeTested();

    new Verifications() {{
        // verify other calls to `dep`, if applicable...
    }};
}
```