# mockito test void Method, override member variable

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm new to unit-testing and mockito but i need to test this class:

```
public class XMLHandler {
    private static final String CONFIG_FILE = "path/to/xml";
    private XMLConfiguration config = null;

    public XMLHandler() {
        try {
            config = new XMLConfiguration(CONFIG_FILE);
            config.setValidating(true);
        } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e );
        }
    }

    public List<ConfigENtries> getEntries() {     
        // do some stuff
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public void removeEntry(int index) {
        // remove entry
    }
}
```

I think i have to override the config variable with a mockup but i don't have a setter, so how would i do this?
And what about removeEntry? How to test a void method?

I hope someone can help me with this

Comment: Possible duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406769/how-to-mock-objects-that-are-not-passed-as-arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406769/how-to-mock-objects-that-are-not-passed-as-arguments)

Comment: Are you at liberty to alter the class?

Comment: With a private constructor, you won't be able to test this in another class.

Comment: yes i can modify the class, the constructor is now public. That was a mistake from my side.

Comment: in the view of user of this class, I will expect the possibility for me to provide the XML file path.  it is fine if you use a default one if I don't provide.  Given a ctor which accept the config file path, testing that is straight-forward

Comment: the path to the xml-file is stored in a config-file. I could modify the constructor to accept a file path but this would never be used except the unit tests. But this is probably the solution with the least effort. Can i mock a file with mockito?

Comment: @SanoJ Mock the object that needs to interact with the file. Note that my solution below avoids the need to specify a file at all.

Comment: Where did...`LOGGER` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are allowed to modify your class, I would suggest the following structure:

```
public class XMLHandler {
  private final XMLConfiguration config;

  public XMLHandler(XMLConfiguration config) {
    this.config = config;
  }

  public List<ConfigENtries> getEntries() {     
    // do some stuff
    return list;
  }

  @Override
  public void removeEntry(int index) {
    // remove entry
  }
}
```

Make sure that `XMLConfiguration` is an *interface*, not a concrete implementation. Then you can mock the `config` parameter passed to your constructor. (*Note: you can mock non-final concrete class too, but using an interface would be preferred*.)

You can then test the public methods of `XMLHandler` and confirm correct behaviour by inspecting the calls made to `config` and asserting the method responses are correct.

Void methods can be tested without problem. You just need some way of determining that the state of your object and the world has been adjusted corrected. So, perhaps you need to call a getter method at the end of your test to ensure values have changed. Or verify expected calls were made to your mock object.

Comment: Mockito can mock concrete classes provided they are not final, so XMLConfiguration does not have to be an interface, though I would suggest it as good practice.

Comment: @ChrisKnight Yes, good point. I should have made that clear. I've edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Although I would also prefer modifying the constructor and pass XMLConfiguration like @DuncanJones suggests (or use some other kind of Dependency Injection), you could use mockito to mock `XMLConfiguration` by using the `@InjectMocks` annotation in your test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class XMLHandlerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    XMLHandler handler = new XMLHandler();

    @Mock
    XMLConfiguration config;

    //...
```