# How to write Junit for Input Stream classes

Tags: java, junit, fileinputstream

How to write Junit for this?

When I debug this, I'm getting `englishFile` as Null in the line 
`englishFile = new FileInputStream(fileName);`

```
    String langCode = getLanguageCode();
    String fileName = "appQuestion_"+langCode+".properties";
    FileInputStream englishFile = null;
    try {
        englishFile = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        engProperties.load(englishFile);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {
        if (null != englishFile) {
            englishFile.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to use mocking so your test is not dependent on reading an actual file from filesystem. There is plenty of mocking frameworks for JUnit - Mockito, EasyMock, Powermock and plenty of others.

Comment: I can use only Mockito because using other frameworks will fail in sonar coverage.

Disadvantage of Mockito is that we cannot mock **"new"** operator.

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920153/test-class-with-a-new-call-in-it-with-mockito?

Comment: Don't write empty catch blocks. If you had done that properly you wouldn't need to debug this at all.

Answer (score 7):

you have at least 4 options

1. use powermock

   ugly, slow, banned in many companies, allows you write bad code, but powerful
2. do integration tests

   prepare files, environment variables and check how does your code behaves when there is no such file. slow but lets you test that code in real world
3. refactor your code to fit unit tests

   move `new` to other class (factory), move `.load` to other class (environmentProvider) and mock those classes in tests. you will get fast tests but you have to change the design. some will argue it will enforce good design, some will argue tests should not have influence on the design.
4. don't test it.

   maybe that code is so small, have no business logic, doesn't change often, will be tested manually by testers. so maybe it's a waste of money to test it. that's easy but risky solution

i would advise you to choose between some mix of 2,3,4 depending on how critical this code is, how often it changes, will it be more complex and what your application is supposed to do. testing interaction with outside world is often trade off between design (complexity, readability etc), speed and risk.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something similar, in my case, testing a file provider API, and I ended up here (almost on time!).

Taking into account what [piotrek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1100135/piotrek) says in his [nice and useful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32517989/how-to-write-junit-for-input-stream-classes/32521880#32521880), and if you really need to test it, I will summarize the way I figured:

> SW Engineering, adding another level of abstraction *(someone said "the
>   way most of the SW problems are solved)*.

Why?

1. Your data input service is providing some interface to read some data, in this case, from the FS.
2. What if in the future the application would read the data from a InMemory Engine, some NoSQL [grid filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_file_system) (as [Mongo's GridFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB#File_storage)), etc, so, why not adding an abstraction layer?

In this way, you would have a clear separation between the data access module, a repository interface, and the data provider, a service or/and API..

For example, you can publish your data with an implementation independent API (it could be a RESTful API):

```
public class DataStorageAPI{
  private DataStorageRepository dataStorageRepository;
  ...
  public InputStreamResource getFile(String fileName){
    InputStream isFile = dataStorageRepository.getFile(fileName);
    return new InputStreamResource(isFile);
}
```

The repository is the one making the access to the file:

```
public class DataStorageRepository{
  public InputStream getFile(String fileName){ ... }
}
```

How?

Your data-interface-service will "point" another specific service that will perform the specific operation. In this way, you only have to mock that specific-service method in the data-interface-service unit test.

```
...
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull; 
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any; 
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
...

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class DataStorageAPITest {

    @InjectMocks
    private DataStorageAPI dataStorageAPI;

    @Mock
    private DataStorageRepository dataStorageRepository;
    ...

    @Test
    public void getFileTest() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

    String fileName = "appQuestion_"+langCode+".properties";
    String expectedFileContent = "some dummy English file content";
    InputStream expectedInputStream =
         new ByteArrayInputStream(expectedFileContent.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    InputStream obtainedInputStreamMock =
         new ByteArrayInputStream(expectedFileContent.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    when(dataStorageRepository.getFile(any()))
      .thenReturn(obtainedInputStreamMock);

    InputStreamResource returnedInputStreamResource = dataStorageAPI.getFile(fileName);
    InputStream resultInputStream = returnedInputStreamResource.getInputStream();

    assertNotNull(returnedInputStreamResource);

    String expected =
          StreamUtils.convertInputStreamToString(expectedInputStream);
    String obtained =
          StreamUtils.convertInputStreamToString(resultInputStream);

    assertEquals(expected, obtained);
    }
}
```