# Mock inner methods using Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am new to Mockito.
I am trying to write jnuit for a service by mocking the db interactions:

I have following classes (just representative of actual classes)

```
public class TestService{

    public Response getTestList(String type){
        list = getListbyType(type);

        return response.entity(list);
    }

    private List getListbyType(String type){
          ...
          ..
          TestDAO testdao = new Testdao(sqlconn);
          list = testdao.getListfromDB(type)
          return list;
   }
}
```

And my test class is something like

```
public class TestServiceTest{

    @InjectMocks
    private TestService testService = new TestService();
    @Test
    public void getTestListTest(){

        List testlist = new List();
        tetslist.add("test1");

        TestDAO testdaomock = mock(TestDAO);
        when(testdaomock.getListfromDB("test")).thenreturn(list);

        list = testService.getTestList(test);
    }
}
```

But when I run this test, it still invokes the actual DB call and retrieves the values from db and not the mocked values, should I mock sql connection and non default constructor? I am clueless.

-- UPDATE

As people have suggested, I moved DAO instantiation to my service constructor and also used Spy, But still my actual DB call is invoked instead of the mock call.

Comment: `testdaomock.getListfromDB("test")` should not compile because `private List getListbyType(String type)` is private. How does it compile?

Comment: getListbyType(String type) is private, but testdaomock.getList‌​fromDB("test") is in DAO class which is public

Comment: `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test class with a new() call in it with Mockito](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920153/test-class-with-a-new-call-in-it-with-mockito)

Comment: The problem of this test is actually poor design of the code under test: one should not instantiate any DAO within the call to a "getter". The only place for that DAO instance is to be a field, instantiated at construction or lazily when required (the test would do the former).

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with the following statement:

```
TestDAO testdao = new Testdao(sqlconn);
```

The instance of TestDAO you got from mock() is not the instance used in `testdao.getListfromDB(type)` that follows `new`

In order to successfully mock, you need to apply the inversion of dependencies throughout. That means `new` must only show up in classes you don't intend to test, such as simplistic factories or Spring config files.

[Update]

If proper IOC is not an option, you can introduce a method that allocates DAO and then `spy()` it. The method would have to be package-private. This is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920153/test-class-with-a-new-call-in-it-with-mockito).

Another option would be to add a package-private constructor taking `testdao` as argument and expressing your default constructor in the terms of that constructor.

Comment: makes sense, but i cannot introduce IOC right now, is there a way to mock this parametarized constructor rather than the default one?

Comment: You could use PowerMock but then you need to use a seperate junit runner see https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage#how-to-mock-construction-of-new-objects

Comment: You can try injecting `TestDAO` into  `TestService` by passing a reference to a `TestDAO` instance in the `getTestList` method. Another way is adding a `TestDAO` attribute in `TestService`, setting a default value e.g. in the default constructor and then adding a setter in `TestService` which would set the `TestDAO` attribute. Then you could use this setter in your test to pass a `TestDAO` mock.

Answer (score 2):

In case you can't change the TestService class (legacy code) there is a possiblity to mock the new instance with PowerMockito (https://github.com/jayway/powermock). This uses a own junit runner (PowerMockRunner) that allows the byte-code manipulation.

Here an example for your code:

```
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class TestServiceTest {

   @Mock
   TestDAO testDaoMock;

   @Test
   public void test() throws Exception {
    List<String> testlist = new ArrayList<>();
    testlist.add("test1");
    when(testDaoMock.getListfromDB(anyString())).thenReturn(testlist);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(TestDAO.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(testDaoMock);
    TestService testService = new TestService();
    Response actualResponse = testService.getTestList("testType");
    assertEquals(expectedResponse, actualResponse);
    }
}
```

You will need to add powermock-api-mockito and powermock-module-junit4 to your dependcies.