# scala: Moking my scala Object that has external dependency

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mocking, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a Object like this:

```
// I want to test this Object
object MyObject {

  protected val retryHandler: HttpRequestRetryHandler = new HttpRequestRetryHandler {
    def retryRequest(exception: IOException, executionCount: Int, context: HttpContext): Boolean = {
      true // implementation
    }
  }

  private val connectionManager: PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager
  val httpClient: CloseableHttpClient = HttpClients.custom
    .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
    .setRetryHandler(retryHandler)
    .build

  def methodPost = {
    //create new context and new Post instance
    val post = new HttpPost("url")
    val res = httpClient.execute(post, HttpClientContext.create)
    // check response code and then take action based on response code
  }

  def methodPut = {
    // same as methodPost except use HttpPut instead HttpPost
  }

}
```

I want to test this object by mocking dependent objects like httpClient. How to achieve this? can i do it using Mokito or any better way? If yes. How? Is there a better design for this class?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is: you created hard-to test code. You can turn [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79) to watch some videos to understand why that is.

The short answer: directly calling *new* in your production code always makes testing harder. You could be using Mockito spies (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920153/test-class-with-a-new-call-in-it-with-mockito) on how that works).

But: the better answer would be to rework your production code; for example to use **dependency injection**. Meaning: instead of creating the objects your class needs itself (by using *new*) ... your class *receives* those objects from somewhere.

The typical (java) approach would be something like:

```
public MyClass() { this ( new SomethingINeed() ); }

MyClass(SomethingINeed incoming) { this.somethign = incoming; }
```

In other words: the normal usage path still calls *new* directly; but for unit testing you provide an alternative constructor that you can use to *inject* the thing(s) your class under test depends on.

Comment: i have thought of dependency injection but couldn't figure out how to implement. One approach i had was to take httpClient as parameter to each method (since object class can't have constructor in Scala like Java..but still Put and Post will have new) but in that case i will loose control on retry and other failure case handling.