# How to mock method that called in other method while using Spring Dependency Injection?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have something like this:

```
public class Class1 {
    @Autowired
    Class2 class2;

    public Object class1Method {
        // Do something
        Object obj = class2.class2Method(arg);
        // Do something with obj
        return somthing;
    }
}
```

I am doing unit testing to Class1 and I want to mock the class2Method. I tried to find solution and I found this:

[Test class with a new() call in it with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920153/test-class-with-a-new-call-in-it-with-mockito)

I understood that this solution works if I do new instance of Class2 in the class1Method, but in my case I use Spring Dependency Injection and I can't figure out how to this.

Comment: Add your test class definition .. are these integration tests?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski no thats why I want to make mock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how did you build your DI with spring you can use something like this if you have `@Autowired` on field

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public Class1Test {

    @InjectMocks
    @Autwired
    private Class1 class1;

    @Mock
    Class2 class2;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void initMocks(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public Object testClass1Method {
        when(class2.class2Method(anyString()).thenReturn(expectedReturn);
        //Now test whatever you need with mocked class2.class2Method 

    }
}
```

It's much easier and you don't need to have spring context up for tests if you have constructor DI (`@Autowired` on constructor)

```
public Class1Test {

    private Class1 class1;

    private Class2 class2;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void initMocks(){
        class2 = mock(Class2.class);
        class1 = new Class1(class2);
    }
   //then use the same approach to mock any methods that you need
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and other question about it: I saw there is a `@Spy` annotation that you can also mock methods with it. What is the differnce between the `@Spy` annotation to `@Mock` annotation for mocking methods?

Comment: @Sagie `@Spy` will use the real object, not Mock object

Answer (score 1):

You should go with

> Mockito

,and have your JUnit class include this at the top `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`. So in your case you can have your Junit like this.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public Class1Test {

    @InjectMocks
    private Class1 class1 = new Class1();

    @Mock
    Class2 class2;

    @Test
    public Object testClass1Method {
        // Now this will get the class2 mock instance when executed
        Object obj = class1.class1Method(arg);

    }
}
```

Comment: So if I want to mock the class2Method I will just do `when(class2.class2Method).thenReturn(theWantededResponseObject)`? And I saw there is a `@Spy` annotation that you can also mock methods with it. What is the differnce between the `@Spy` annotation to `@Mock` annotation for mocking methods?

Comment: A mock in mockito is a normal mock whereas  spy in mockito is a partial mock

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can write Unit test for `Class1` using `Mockito` :

```
public Class1Test {

    @InjectMocks
    private Class1 class1;

    @Mock
    private Class2 class2;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void initMocks(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_method1() {

        Object obj = //instantiate it here...,

        Mockito.doReturn(obj).when(class2.class2Method(anyString());

        Assert.assertEquals(class1.class1Method(), something);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, and other question about it: I saw there is a `@Spy` annotation that you can also mock methods with it. What is the differnce between the `@Spy` annotation to `@Mock` annotation for mocking methods?

Comment: `Mock` is made to mock fully the object it will mock all the methods of this object, however with `Spy` it will mock it partially and keep some of it's original methods as it is.

Comment: For example we don't need to mock methods of `ArrayList` so we could use `@Spy` in this case instead of `Mock`