# Mockito: Spying calls within the constructor (Java)

Tags: java, mockito

**This is not a duplicate of [Test class with a new() call in it with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920153/test-class-with-a-new-call-in-it-with-mockito). I'm trying to write a test to verify that certain methods are being called within the constructor of my spy object (mockToyFacade).**

The class under test is ToyFactoryFacade.  The idea is clients interact with the ToyFactoryFacade (which wraps a ToyFactory) to generate ToyFacades, which itself is a wrapper around the Toy object.

#### What I am trying to verify with Mockito?

I want to verify that **addToyName(toyName)** and **addCreationTime(creationTimestamp)** are being called on the ToyFacade.  Both of these methods are called in the constructor of the ToyFacade.

#### What's the issue?

When I try to spy the ToyFacade, and verify that both aforementioned methods are called, I receive an error, which says **"Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock."**  When I call the methods separately (i.e., not via the constructor), the verification check out correctly. **I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly.**

### Test Code

```
public class ToyFactoryFacadeTest {
   private Toy mockToy;
   private ToyFacade mockToyFacade;
   // System under test.
   private ToyFactoryFacade toyFactoryFacade;
   private ToyFactory mockToyFactory;
   @Before
   public void setup() {
        mockToy = mock(Toy.class);
        mockToyFacade = spy(new ToyFacade(mockToy, "Phone", System.currentTimeMillis()));
        mockToyFactory = mock(ToyFactory.class);
        toyFactoryFacade  = new ToyFactoryFacade(mockToyFactory) {
            @Override
            public Toy getToyFacade(String toyName, long creationTimestamp){
                return mockToyFacade;
            }
        };  
    }

    @Test
    public void testToyFactoryFacade() {
        toyFactoryFacade.initializeAndGetToy("Phone", System.currentTimeMillis());
        verify(mockToyFacade).addToyName("Phone");
        verify(mockToyFacade).addCreationTime(anyLong());
    }
}
```

### Source Code

```
public class ToyFactoryFacade { 
    private final ToyFactory toyFactory;
    public ToyFactoryFacade(ToyFactory toyFactory) {
      this.toyFactory = toyFactory;
    }

    public ToyFacade initializeAndGetToy(String toyName, long creationTimestamp)
    {
        getToyFacade(toyName, creationTimestamp);
    }

    // For testing.
    protected ToyFacade getToyFacade(String toyName, long creationTimestamp 
    {
        return new ToyFacade(toyFactory.newToy(), toyName, creationTimestamp);
    }
}

public class ToyFactory {
    public Toy newToy() {
     return new Toy();
    }
} 

public class ToyFacade {
    private final Toy toy;
    public ToyFacade(Toy toy, String toyName, long creationTimeStamp) {
        this.toy = toy;
        addToyName(toyName);
        addCreationTime(creationTimestamp);
  }

    public void addToyName(String name) {
        toy.addToyName(toyName);
    }

    public void addCreationTime(long timestamp) {
        toy.addCreationTime(timestamp);
    }
}

public class Toy {
    public String toyName;
    public String creationTimestamp;
    public void addToyName(String name) {
        toyName = name;
    }

    public void addCreationTime(long timestamp) {
        creationTimestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is **not** a duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898462/mockito-spying-java-constructor-method-calls](Test class with a new() call in it with Mockito).  Here, I am spying a class (ToyFacade) that makes calls to 2 helper methods when its constructor is initialized.  My question is why I can't verify that those 2 method were called.  Dawood's point is that I should really be verifying the effects of those two calls on the mockToy object, as opposed to verifying that the calls were made on the ToyFacade spy (mockToyFacade) itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test isn't doing what you expect because the method calls that you're trying to verify have already taken place before you create your spy.  What you really want to do is to test the effect of those two method calls, rather than the calls themselves.  This would look something like

```
verify(mockToy).addToyName("Phone");
verify(mockToy).addCreationTime(timestamp);
```

where `timestamp` is whatever you pass in in the `setUp` method.

Comment: Thanks Dawood.  As you point out, I did see that testing the effects of those calls on the backing toy object (mockToy) worked as expected.  Out of curiosity, is there a way to verify that those calls on the mockToyFacade happened, in addition to the desired effect on the mockToy object being observed?

Comment: Not that I know of.  And if there were, you shouldn't use it.  Because when you test a class, you should be verifying its effect on what goes on outside the class itself.  If you find yourself testing the mechanisms inside the class itself, you've got a code smell.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!