# Test an overridden method of an inner class with JUnit and Mockito

Tags: java, mockito, rx-java2, junit5

I have a method in a class I need to test. The method uses an external class that I need to mock, so the external class doesn't get tested or executes its dependencies. The special challenge is: one method of the external class gets overridden. Method looks like this:

```java
public void fetchLocalData(final String source, final ObservableEmitter<String> destination) {
   final List<String> options = Arrays.asList("recursive","allFiles","includeDir");
   // This class comes from a package
   final DirScan dirscan = new DirScan(source, options) {
       @Override
       protected Action getResult(final String result) {
           destination.onNext(result);
           return Action.Continue;
       }
   };
   dirscan.scan();
   destination.onComplete();
}
```

I tried:

```java
    DirScan scanner = mock(DirScan.class);
    when(scanner.scan()).thenReturn("one").thenReturn("two");
```

That didn't work. What do I miss? How would I need to refactor to make this testable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Test class with a new() call in it with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920153/test-class-with-a-new-call-in-it-with-mockito)

Comment: Not really. The new keyword isn’t my main issue here, but the overwritten method that needs access to method level objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace the `dirscan` with a mock (or a spy) you'll need to refactor your class that it's a dependency or parameter. Alternatively you could use `PowerMockito`'s `whenNew` functionality.

Lets assume you change your class and instead of the `String source` you provide the `DirScan` object as a parameter. You would need to have some kind of creation method for dirscan elsewhere (might be a `static` method).

```java
final List<String> options = Arrays.asList("recursive","allFiles","includeDir");

public DirScan createDirScan(String source) {

   // This class comes from a package
   final DirScan dirscan = new DirScan(source, options) {
       @Override
       protected Action getResult(final String result) {
           destination.onNext(result);
           return Action.Continue;
       }
   };

   return dirscan;
}
```

```java
public void fetchLocalData(final DirScan dirscan, final ObservableEmitter<String> destination) {
    dirscan.scan();
    destination.onComplete();
}
```

Juding from your question you seem to want to test the interaction with the destination object, so you do not want to mock the `dirscan` object (because if you do there won't be any interaction). You might want to use a `spy` and only replace the `getResult` method.

In your test now you could then simply pass a `spy` for the `dirscan` object and 
define the behaviour of it with `thenAnswer`.

```java
final ObservableEmitter<String> destination = ...

DirScan dirscan = Mockito.spy(createDirScan(source, destination));

Mockito.when(dirscan.getResult(Mockito.any(String.class))).thenAnswer((Answer<Action>) invocation -> {
    String result = invocation.getArgument(0);
    destination.onNext(result);

    return Action.Continue;
});

classUnderTest.fetchLocalData(dirscan, destination);
```

---

At this point you might notice that its probably better to **not** use a spy and just use the real `DirScan` object. Using the `spy` to do what you intend to do with the overriden method looks like overkill to me.

The real object has to work for this test to be of value, so you might as well test the real thing.

Comment: If you absolutly need to mock `DirScan` you could still use the `doAnswer` on the `scan` operation (assuming its a `void` method) and trigger the `destination.onNext` calls from there. However that makes the test look even stranger. Maybe if you can provide more information about which parts of the `DirScan` object interact with the `getResult` method it might be possible to figure out which parts of the class need to be mocked so the external dependencies do not need to be invoked.

Comment: The DirScan class comes from an external library and uses JNI calls to query a backend system. During unit tests that’s not available so I need to mock DirScan to avoid the C calls. I’ll refactor. Thx for the pointers

Comment: In that case your aim should be to replace those `JNI` calls (or the methods that trigger them). Using a `spy` in that case should be ok, but whether that can be done depends on the implementation.

Comment: The DirScan class with its JNI calls is a library I can use, but not change

Comment: That's ok. For spying you do not need to change the code, the only issue might be the limitation of the `mockito` framework to mock certain things. If its a public library I could take a look, to check whether its possible.