# how to mock the method call which is not done by some dependency of the class?

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I am trying to write JUnits for some class which is as follows

```
class C{
    public C fun(D d){
       // fetch some data from database using object of D
       // do some operations on that data 
       // create an object of C using this data
       // return that object of C
    }
 }
@Component
class toBeTested{
   @Autowired private A a;
   @Autowired private B b;
   public C methodToBeTested(){
        C c = new C(a.getD()).fun();
        return c;
   } 
}
```

I want  to test methodToBeTested() method. Please tell is there any way In which we can mock the method calls of object D present in class C while execution of fun() method. Or If there is some other easy way to handle this situation in mockito. All I have found until now is this [Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920153/test-class-with-a-new-call-in-it-with-mockito) but still I am not clear how to use this in my situation

Comment: Class `C` has an `@Autowired` annotation inside it, but in your `methodToBeTested` you're instantiating it yourself using `new`. Because of that, `d` in your `C` object will be `null`. You should not instantiate Spring beans such as class `C` yourself using `new` - that way you bypass Spring's dependency injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `@Autowired` in class C, this C should be managed by Spring, otherwise the "autowiring magic of D inside C won't happen"

But if so, why do you create a new instance of C in class `toBeTested`? It doesn't really make sence.

So you should:

1. Place `@Component` on class C so that Spring will manage it.
2. Modify class `toBeTested`:

```
@Component
class toBeTested{
   @Autowired private A a;
   @Autowired private B b;
   @Autowired private C c; 
   public C methodToBeTested(){
        return c.fun();
   } 
}
```

Its quite strange to see c.fun() that returns itself, is it a builder or something? Maybe you should make it 'prototype scope' and then the solution is slightly different, but since its not mentioned in the question, I don't have enough details so I'll leave the answer as is...

**Update 1**

Now when its clear that class C for reasons which are beyond the control of OPs is not managed by spring, there are two options:

1. Use PowerMock/Power Mockito if you have to preserve class `toBeTested` in its current form (with `new C() in the method to be tested`. This approach in general considered a bad practice use it only if you don't have another choice. These tools can mock the creation of object (new) and substitute C with some stub on the fly.
2. If you can change the class `toBeTested` - use dependency injection:

```
public class ToBeTested {
   @Autowired private A a;
   @Autowired private B b;
   @Autowired private CFactory cFactory; 

   public C methodToBeTested() {
      return cFactory.create(a.getD()).fun();
   }  
}

interface CFactory {
    C create(D d);
}

@Component
public class DefaultCFactoryImpl implements CFactory {
   public C createC(D d) {
      return new C(d);
   }
}
```

This approach is much better because it allows to substitute the factory with the implementation that will create a mock of C or whatever you'll find appropriate for the test.

Comment: I agree with your thoughts but these are the legacy codes on which I have to work on. Due to security concerns I am not supposed to show the actual code on which I am working on. I have translated those codes into exampler form Probably I may be wrong somewhere. Class C is a Client class which has and method fun is about getting certain views. and one mistake on my part  which I have just noted is that the autowired thing is not there. please look at the code again after a minute or so I am Editing accordingly.

Comment: I see, but still, even after edit, you have in class C: `@Autowired D d;` Did you mean that Autowired should not be there and this class is not managed by spring?

Comment: Strange but I have removed it. please reload your page again

Comment: @NipulSindwani, got it, please see and update on my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Mark Bramnik

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to use a constructor injection.

But if you don't want to refactor, you can use `@InjectMocks` from mockito.

```
class ToBeTestedTest {
   @Mock private A a;
   @Mock private B b;
   @InjectMocks ToBeTested toBeTested; // mockito will inject your mocks

   @Before
   public void setUpMocks() {
      when(a.getSomeParameter()).thenReturn(new DummyObject())
   }
}
```

Comment: So is there no way in which I can directly give the value of object C method call. instead of executing its code. Is it compulsory for me to execute code for fun()  method. Can't we mock it as we do with other methods like getSomeParameter.

Comment: I've updated my answer a bit. You can't mock `C#fun()` call. But you can put some mock object in `C` constructor. But it's better just to inject `C` like `A` and `B`. Then you'll be able to mock it.

Comment: as you have edited your code but In my opinion that mock call will return an object of someParameter only. I am asking about If there is any way in which we can get an object of C to bypass all the execution of method fun() some thing like this when(new object of C is formed and fun is called for that object ) then return an object of C as stubbing. I hope you got my question. I am not sure if this can be done or not.

Comment: short answer - no. To do it you have to refactor your code and inject `C`. look at @mark-bramnik answer.

Comment: I have edited my code I made some mistake please abandon that. Please have a fresh look at it.