# How to mock a new object creation in Javaa

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to mock a new object creation in java, but unable to do so.

this is the code.

```
    public class testClass() {
    private final MyObject myobject;
    private SecondObject secondObject;

    public testClass(MyObject myObject) {
        this.myObject = myObject;
    } 

    public void init() {
        secondObject = new SecondObject(myobject,100,100);
    }
}
```

Please explain how to mock secondObject in this example.

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920153/test-class-with-a-new-call-in-it-with-mockito

Answer (score 1):

The design of `testClass` makes it difficult to test (ironically). It has a dependency on a second class that is hidden. Your best option is to expose this dependency:

```
interface SecondObjectCreator {
    SecondObject create(TestClass obj, int val1, int val2);
}

class TestClass {
    public TestClass(MyObject obj, SecondObjectCreator creator);
}
```

This redesign makes the code easy to test as you can inject a mock that behaves in a variety of ways.